# Chrome copies entire html despite using "user-select: none" because of neighbor div

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the example I need the div with id of `div2` won't be able to be copied at all.
If its stands by itself there is no problem at all cause it can not be selected by the user mouse.

The problem is if it has a select-able neighbors divs, the user may uses the mouse to select the first and third divs so the copy action will copy the `div2` div as well.

```
<div id="div1" style="user-select:text;">Text1</div>
<div id="div2" style="user-select:none;">Text2</div>
<div id="div3" style="user-select:text;">Text3</div>
```

Any suggestion for ways not allowing copying of `div2` (with neighbors)?

Comment: @PedroSturmer Hey, this not answering my problem, I'm already using `user-select: none`.

Comment: Maybe just add a "copy to clipboard" button for the user and use something like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) and some custom logic on what to copy if this is just to improve user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better prevent copying like this (although it is non-standard (refer to **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy)**), it is supported in all major browsers including IE) – if your real prupose is to prevent copying:

```
<div onCopy="alert('No copying or cutting.'); return false;"
      onCut="alert('No copying or cutting.'); return false;"
      style="-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;">
</div>
```